# Can i port theme settings also in a feature

Tags: 7

I tried to port a theme settings like default theme, other theme settings in a feature. But when i enable this feature along with the theme on a new website. It does not take effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theme settings are usually stored as a variable, which is exportable with strongarm. Note that some things in the theming system is cached.

Comment: I see the feature in new website that 'theme_default' variable is taken effect and it says its default. But the theme was not still enabled

Comment: Most likely the problem is that features don't change the variable fast enough then, or like I said earlier, the cache is messing with you.